# Find invoice.payment_succeeded against subscription id

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

My site was down for a week, and few subscription installment was done during the week. But my website did not capture this(using web hook for invoice.payment_succeeded).

I have queried my database and have subscription ids with me.
But how do I get the event that triggered invoice.payment_succeeded. So that I can pass the same to web-hook method and database will be updated.

- First I queried with subscription id.
  `https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions/sub_XXXXXX` I get invoice id
- Second I queried with invoice id.
  `https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/in_XXXXXX` and gets

  ```
     "status_transitions": {
         "finalized_at": 1565706891,
         "marked_uncollectible_at": null,
         "paid_at": 1565706893,
         "voided_at": null
      },
  ```

  This shows payment was made.
- Third I then queried with paid date (Timestamp)

> https://api.stripe.com/v1/events?created=1565706893&type=invoice.payment_succeeded

and gets event triggered for invoice.payment_succeeded response during that date.

But at times, I can find no events created during the "paid_at": 1565706893, value. 
What am I missing here. Or is there any alternate solution to find event id for  type invoice.payment_succeeded using subscription id.

Comment: Hi Paul, it is correct to use the /v1/events listing API from Stripe. and you would need to provide two parameters 
1.` type` -> Specify as `invoice.payment_succeeded`
2. To narrow down the events, use `created` range. Take note created is a range which you could specify {gt, lt}. However in your query you've specified only a time point. 

By default, the listing returns 10 events per API call, you will need to perform pagination to pull data for all pages. (Stripe-PHP supports auto pagination like https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto?lang=php )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions/sub_XXXXXX
will fetch only latest_invoice id. Are you sure that you take the correct invoice id.

You can also try this if you only want event id associated [https://api.stripe.com/v1/events?related_object= SUBSCRIPTIONID&type=invoice.payment_succeeded](https://api.stripe.com/v1/events?related_object=%3CSUBSCRIPTIONID%3E&type=invoice.payment_succeeded)

Here you can find all the success events created for particular subscription. Hope this helps.(Dosen't know if its official, couldn't find, but you can try)